# "Facility for speaking" vs. "facility to speak"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prepositions, gerund-vs-infinitive

Which one would you use:

> - I lost my facility to speak.
> - I lost my facility for speaking.

Or does either work?

Answer (score 1):

I think both are wrong, if one equates use with acceptability.

In medicine, we say "he lost his [faculty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faculty) **of** speech", where faculty is the ability, power; an inherent capability, power, or function; a natural aptitude. Googling ___ gets ___ hits: "he lost the faculty **of** speech" (14.8K), "he lost his faculty **of** speech" (13K), "he lost the faculty **to** speak" (6), "he lost his faculty **to** speak" (1).

Facility is an ability to do or learn something well and easily; a natural aptitude. Googling: "he lost his facility **to** speak" (7 hits), "he lost the facility to speak" (0 hits), "he lost his facility to speak" (7 hits), and "*I lost my facility for speaking** gets 3 hits, two of which are this question.